# Datatables row grouping - how to add rowcount per group and expand/collapse all

Tags: jquery, datatables, grouping

I am using Datatables Collapsible/Expandable Grouping.
http://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/collapsibleGroups.html

I have configured it so that all groups collapsed in the initial view.

I would really like to add the rowcount (number of rows per group) in the group header to make the row grouping more informative.  It would let the user how much extra information to expect when clicking to expand the group.

It would also be very useful to add expand/collapse all buttons.

Can anyone help to find away to add these features?

I've set up a jsfiddle to show what I'm trying to accomplish:
http://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/4Rkb3/36/

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: k..how can i download this plugin? can u paste the code in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle link now in the post above.  Thank you in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#example').dataTable({
                    "bLengthChange": false,
                    "bPaginate": false,
                    "bJQueryUI": true
                }).rowGrouping({
                    bExpandableGrouping: true,
                    bExpandSingleGroup: false,
                    iExpandGroupOffset: -1,
                    asExpandedGroups: [""]
                });

                GridRowCount();
            });

            function GridRowCount() {
                $('span.rowCount-grid').remove();
                $('input.expandedOrCollapsedGroup').remove();

                $('.dataTables_wrapper').find('[id|=group-id]').each(function () {
                    var rowCount = $(this).nextUntil('[id|=group-id]').length;
                    $(this).find('td').append($('<span />', { 'class': 'rowCount-grid' }).append($('<b />', { 'text': rowCount })));
                });

                $('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.dataTables_filter').append($('<input />', { 'type': 'button', 'class': 'expandedOrCollapsedGroup collapsed', 'value': 'Expanded All Group' }));

                $('.expandedOrCollapsedGroup').live('click', function () {
                    if ($(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
                        $(this).addClass('expanded').removeClass('collapsed').val('Collapse All Group').parents('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.collapsed-group').trigger('click');
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).addClass('collapsed').removeClass('expanded').val('Expanded All Group').parents('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.expanded-group').trigger('click');
                    }
                });
            };


// ------------ Css -------------------------//
       .rowCount-grid
        {
            float: right;
            font-size: 15px;
            color: Red;
            padding-right: 250px;
        }
```