# Datatables row grouping - how to add a checkbox to show or exclude rows

Tags: jquery, checkbox, datatables, grouping

I am using Datatables Collapsible/Expandable Grouping.

I have configured it so that all groups collapsed in the initial view.

Thanks to ThulasiRam's help, I've integrated group rowcount and collapse/expand all features. Thanks to AbstractChaos' help I've also integrated a search/reset search which opens/closes groups which match the search criteria

[Datatables row grouping - how to add rowcount per group and expand/collapse all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460421/datatables-row-grouping-how-to-add-rowcount-per-group-and-expand-collapse-all)

[Datatables row grouping - how to expand to show search matches and add reset search field button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948699/datatables-row-grouping-how-to-expand-to-show-search-matches-and-add-reset-sea)

I need to add one more additional feature:  a checkbox to exclude/include records which are marked as "legacy" in the status column.

I've set up a jsfiddle to show what I'm trying to accomplish: http://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/NeMXd/18/

Any help would really be appreciated!!

Comment: Individual checkboxes for each legacy row ? or a single checkbox to select all legacy's ?

Comment: One checkbox at the top of the table to include the legacy's, like in the jsfiddle.  If the checkbox is not checked the legacy rows should be excluded.  Thank you in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Datatables Collapsible/Expandable Grouping but something along the way of

```
$(window).on( "click", '#showlegacy', function( e ) {
    if(! $(this).is(':checked')) {
        ref.fnFilter('Current', 3);
    }
});
```

should work.

http://jsfiddle.net/NeMXd/19/

Comment: Unchecking the checkbox works GREAT!  The legacy rows are hidden.  Rechecking the checkbox needs to restore the legacy rows.  Can you help to make the check/uncheck manage this?  Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Hi Nicola!  I've just seen your answer to a similar question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226614/datatables-create-filter-checkbox
Could you help me to adapt this to work on the status column based on the value "legacy" or "current"?  Thank you very much for your great work!!!