# datatables create filter checkbox

Tags: datatables

Does anyone have examples on how to create a Datatablest filter checkbox? I want to display only rows that have a value above X or below Y being controlled by a checkbox.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You would have to write your own custom filtering function but after that the code would be vary simple

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
        var checked = $('#checkbox').is(':checked');

        if (checked && aData[4] > 1.5) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!checked && aData[4] <= 1.5) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
    $('#checkbox').on("click", function(e) {
        oTable.fnDraw();
    });

});​
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/WVYNX/2/

Comment: Hi Nicola, that is exactly what I don't have, how do I create a filter function for datatables?

Comment: @AdamSurfari i updated my answer, basically now if the checkbox is checked and the fifth column is > 1.5 i show the row, if it's unchecked and it's <= 1.5 i show the row

Comment: Hi Nicola, I now have the problem that all my tables get this filter applied. How do I apply it to just one table?

Comment: @AdamSurfari: `if ( oSettings.nTable != document.getElementById( 'your_table_id' );{            return true;}`

Comment: I took Nicola's fiddle one step further and allowed to filter by distinct values of a column http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/z7wJ5/ additionally someone posted this in the dataTables forum: http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/3118/range-filter-for-single-table-in-multi-table-page/p1

Comment: Nicola - thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. You da' bomb!

Comment: For newer DataTables 1.10+ when you initialize table with DataTable(), use newer draw() API method instead.Use  `oTable.draw()` instead of `oTable.fnDraw()`